# Mentioning of celebration of Eid-Al-Adha in Quran

Tags: quran, animals, sacrifice, eid-ul-adha, udhiyyah

I know there is mention of the incident in the Quran where Ibrahim has a dream in which Allah commands him to sacrifice his son, Ismail, as a sign of obedience to God. 
But I wanted to understand/know if there is any mention of the celebration of Eid-Al-Adha in the Quran to commemorate this incident by Muslim followers all around the world every year. 
Just want to make it clear that I am not talking about the mentioning of the permission to eat halal animals in the Quran which Allah has made permissible for us but I want to know the mentioning of the ruling to sacrifice halal animals on the occasion of Eid-Al-Adha in Quran.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is mention of the sacrifice on Hajj and Eid al-Adha is essentially a cognate of the same. Refer to verses like  [2:196](https://quran.com/2/196?translations=20), [5:2](https://quran.com/5/2?translations=20),  [22:28](https://quran.com/22/28?translations=20),  [22:34](https://quran.com/22/34?translations=20) ,[22:36](https://quran.com/22/36?translations=20) and there are also more general verses on sacrifice like [6:162](https://quran.com/6/162?translations=20) and [108:2](https://quran.com/108/2?translations=20) which are sometimes interpreted to mean the one on Eid al-Adha. Also Abraham عليه السلام sacrificed an animal as that is what ذبح means in  [37:107](https://quran.com/37/107?translations=20)  and we have been commanded to follow his example [16:123](https://quran.com/16/123?translations=20).